# Reference to "this" changed inside Sortables Class

Tags: mootools

I was testing Jakobs patch on the Sortables Class and [this line](https://github.com/jakobholmelund/mootools-more/blob/master/Source/Drag/Sortables.js#L194) `this.reset()` gave me a `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`.

I don't understand why since the Class [has a method reset](https://github.com/jakobholmelund/mootools-more/blob/master/Source/Drag/Sortables.js#L212-L215).

So my solution was to a `var self = this;` inside the same `end:` method ([here](https://github.com/SergioCrisostomo/mootools-more/blob/fix-1116/Source/Drag/Sortables.js#L187)), and called `self.reset();` in the same line as I had `this.reset();` before. Worked good. Why?

Then just to check (I suspected already) I did a `console.log(this == self)` and gave `false`.

Why does using `self` work but not `this`?

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7n8Ve/1/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In javascript the `this` keyword change accordingly with the execution context

- in global code `this` refer to the `global` object
- inside `eval` the scope is the same as the calling context one, if no context provided then is the same as above
- in all the case below if the **this argument** passed to `.bind` `.call` or `.apply` is not an object (or `null`) `this` will be the `global` object
- when using a function which has been binded to a specific object using `.bind` then `this` refers to the **this argument** passed to bind, the function is now *permabinded*.
- when running a function the context is provided from the caller, if before the function call operator `()` there is a dot(`.`) or a `[]` operator then `this` refers to the part on the left of such operator, unless the function is *permabinded* to something else or we are using `.call` or `.apply` if so `this` refers to the **this argument** unless the function was previously *permabinded*;
- if before the function call operator `()` there neither the `.` nor the `[]` operators then `this` will refer to the `global` object (unless the function stores the result of the `.bind` function)
- when running a constructor function (basically when using `new`) `this` refers to the object we are creating

now when using the `use strict directive` things changes a bit, mostly instead of the global object when the context is not given `this` will be `null`, but not in all the cases. 
I rarely use "use strict" so I just suggest to try it by yourself when in need.

now, what happens when a function is cached inside a variable like this:

`var cache = 'A.foo'`

if that you lose the context in which the original function was stored, so in this case *foo* will not be anymore a property on the instance *A* and when you run it using

`cache()`

the context will be evaluated using the rules I wrote above in this case the this will refer to the `global` object.

Comment: no it won't, it's a chained method and context is preserved to the class instance that implements chain. hence `this == this.element.get('morph');`

Answer (score 1):

The semantics of "this" in Javascript are not what is expected by OO programmers.  The symbol "this" refers to the dynamic/runtime calling context, not the lexicographic context.  For example, if you have an object A with "method" and then do `B.method = A.method; B.method();` then the context is now B and that is what this will point to.  The difference becomes very apparent in "handler" type situations where the calling context is usually the object with the handler installed.

Your solution using self is sound.

Comment: DrC, thank you for feedbak! I am aware of the practical use of `self` vs `this`. In this case I have `A.method = function(){ var self = this; [6 lines of code here] console.log(self == this);}` and I get a __false__. All inside the same method. This is what I would like to understand better since both should point to same object.

Comment: But it isn't in the same method.  The reset call is in a sub-function that is registered as a handler.  When it gets called, this will probably reference a DOM element.

Answer (score 1):

kentaromiura's answer is absolutely right.

That said, mootools provides `function.bind()` as  a way to decide what `this` will refer inside of your function. this means that if you simply do this :

```
        var destroy = function () {
            `bind() [...]
            this.reset();
        }.bind(this);
```

it will work as you intended (that is, `this` will be the same inside of `destroy()` and outside).

Now, a lot of coders will balk at fiddling with the context, with good reason as it is very difficult to read and maintain. But here you have it and I think `bind()` is a very nifty trick of mootools.

Comment: Thanks for feedback `+1` - yes, MooTools has some really nifty tricks indeed. That's why I love it :)